# Install tensorboard on python 2.7, met cachetools version mismatch

Tags: tensorflow, pip, tensorboard

I'm trying to install tensorboard with python2.7, but met a version mismatch, and here is the command

```
pip install tensorboard
```

```
Collecting tensorboard
Downloading http:/.../tensorboard-2.1.0-py2-none-any.whl (3.8MB)
....
Collecting cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0 (from google-auth<2,>=1.6.3->tensorboard)
  Downloading http://.../cachetools-4.0.0.tar.gz
cachetools requires Python '~= 3.5' but the running Python is 2.7.16
```

Answer (score 1):

After hours of searching,
For those who encountered this recently, who still using old tensorflow version with python 2.7.
You should notice this:

```
Releases prior to 1.6.0 were published under the tensorflow-tensorboard name 
and may be found at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow-tensorboard.
```

from https://pypi.org/project/tensorboard/

As for me, with python2.7 and self compiled tensorflow 1.11.0, just use this would be fine

```
pip install tensorflow-tensorboard
```

Instead of this

```
pip install tensorboard
cachetools requires Python '~= 3.5' but the running Python is 2.7.16
```